# How to terminate TLS in Envoy proxy

Tags: ssl, envoyproxy

I am scouting through a lot of Envoy documentation but have not found a satisfactory answer yet. Our requirement is simple to terminate the TLS connection at Envoy proxy and send the upstream connection (upstream means the backend traffic) over the HTTP/unencrypted channel.

My use case is really simple:

1. The clients want to talk to Envoy over HTTPS
2. Envoy terminates the TLS connection and connects to the backend using HTTP (Our backend pool exposes both HTTP and HTTPS ports but we specifically want to connect to HTTP port)
3. We are using Dynamic Forward Proxy and a few basic envoy HTTP filters which do the host rewriting, there is no other fancy logic in Envoy

*We would need something like this but I don't see it out of the box anywhere - https://github.com/envoyproxy/envoy/pull/14634*

Current envoy.config

```
admin:
  access_log_path: "/etc/logs/envoy/envoy.log"
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 20000
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: host_manipulation
      address:
        socket_address:
          protocol: TCP
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 443
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: gateway
                      domains:
                        - "*"
                      require_tls: EXTERNAL_ONLY
                      routes:
                        - match:
                            prefix: "/"
                          route:
                            cluster: dynamic_forward_proxy_cluster
                            host_rewrite_path_regex:
                              pattern:
                                google_re2: { }
                                regex: "^/(.+)/(.+)/.+$"
                              substitution: \2-\1.mesh
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.dynamic_forward_proxy
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.dynamic_forward_proxy.v3.FilterConfig
                      dns_cache_config:
                        name: dynamic_forward_proxy_cache_config
                        dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
          transport_socket:
            name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
              common_tls_context:
                tls_certificates:
                  - certificate_chain:
                      filename: "/ca/tls.crt"
                    private_key:
                      filename: "/ca/tls.key"
  clusters:
    - name: dynamic_forward_proxy_cluster
      connect_timeout: 1s
      lb_policy: CLUSTER_PROVIDED
      cluster_type:
        name: envoy.clusters.dynamic_forward_proxy
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.clusters.dynamic_forward_proxy.v3.ClusterConfig
          dns_cache_config:
            name: dynamic_forward_proxy_cache_config
            dns_lookup_family: V4_ONLY
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            validation_context:
              trust_chain_verification: ACCEPT_UNTRUSTED
```

Comment: Update: It is observed that if you do not add the transport_socket block in the cluster definition, the request forwarding will happen in an unencrypted way.  (The last block with name - envoy.transport_sockets.tls)

Comment: Did you got success? I'm searching for the same thing

Answer (score -1):

If you wish to connect to http port - HTTPS to HTTP,
your configuration looks ok, just use HTTP port in the cluster's IP
This is an example for HTTPS to HTTP configuration:

```
static_resources:
  listeners:
  - address:
      socket_address:
        address: 0.0.0.0
        port_value: 10000
    filter_chains:
    - filters:
      - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
          codec_type: AUTO
          stat_prefix: ingress_http
          route_config:
            name: local_route
            virtual_hosts:
            - name: app
              domains:
              - "*"
              routes:
              - match:
                  prefix: "/"
                route:
                  cluster: service-http
          http_filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.http.router
            typed_config:
              "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.DownstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
            # The following self-signed certificate pair is generated using:
            # $ openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout a/front-proxy-key.pem -out  a/front-proxy-crt.pem -days 3650 -nodes -subj '/CN=front-envoy'
            #
            # Instead of feeding it as an inline_string, certificate pair can also be fed to Envoy
            # via filename. Reference: https://envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/api-v3/config/core/v3/base.proto#config-core-v3-datasource.
            #
            # Or in a dynamic configuration scenario, certificate pair can be fetched remotely via
            # Secret Discovery Service (SDS). Reference: https://envoyproxy.io/docs/envoy/latest/configuration/security/secret.
            - certificate_chain:
                inline_string: |
                  -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
                  MIICqDCCAZACCQCquzpHNpqBcDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADAWMRQwEgYDVQQDDAtm
                  cm9udC1lbnZveTAeFw0yMDA3MDgwMTMxNDZaFw0zMDA3MDYwMTMxNDZaMBYxFDAS
                  BgNVBAMMC2Zyb250LWVudm95MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKC
                  AQEAthnYkqVQBX+Wg7aQWyCCb87hBce1hAFhbRM8Y9dQTqxoMXZiA2n8G089hUou
                  oQpEdJgitXVS6YMFPFUUWfwcqxYAynLK4X5im26Yfa1eO8La8sZUS+4Bjao1gF5/
                  VJxSEo2yZ7fFBo8M4E44ZehIIocipCRS+YZehFs6dmHoq/MGvh2eAHIa+O9xssPt
                  ofFcQMR8rwBHVbKy484O10tNCouX4yUkyQXqCRy6HRu7kSjOjNKSGtjfG+h5M8bh
                  10W7ZrsJ1hWhzBulSaMZaUY3vh5ngpws1JATQVSK1Jm/dmMRciwlTK7KfzgxHlSX
                  58ENpS7yPTISkEICcLbXkkKGEQIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCmj6Hg
                  vwOxWz0xu+6fSfRL6PGJUGq6wghCfUvjfwZ7zppDUqU47fk+yqPIOzuGZMdAqi7N
                  v1DXkeO4A3hnMD22Rlqt25vfogAaZVToBeQxCPd/ALBLFrvLUFYuSlS3zXSBpQqQ
                  Ny2IKFYsMllz5RSROONHBjaJOn5OwqenJ91MPmTAG7ujXKN6INSBM0PjX9Jy4Xb9
                  zT+I85jRDQHnTFce1WICBDCYidTIvJtdSSokGSuy4/xyxAAc/BpZAfOjBQ4G1QRe
                  9XwOi790LyNUYFJVyeOvNJwveloWuPLHb9idmY5YABwikUY6QNcXwyHTbRCkPB2I
                  m+/R4XnmL4cKQ+5Z
                  -----END CERTIFICATE-----
              private_key:
                inline_string: |
                  -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
                  MIIEvQIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKcwggSjAgEAAoIBAQC2GdiSpVAFf5aD
                  tpBbIIJvzuEFx7WEAWFtEzxj11BOrGgxdmIDafwbTz2FSi6hCkR0mCK1dVLpgwU8
                  VRRZ/ByrFgDKcsrhfmKbbph9rV47wtryxlRL7gGNqjWAXn9UnFISjbJnt8UGjwzg
                  Tjhl6EgihyKkJFL5hl6EWzp2Yeir8wa+HZ4Achr473Gyw+2h8VxAxHyvAEdVsrLj
                  zg7XS00Ki5fjJSTJBeoJHLodG7uRKM6M0pIa2N8b6HkzxuHXRbtmuwnWFaHMG6VJ
                  oxlpRje+HmeCnCzUkBNBVIrUmb92YxFyLCVMrsp/ODEeVJfnwQ2lLvI9MhKQQgJw
                  tteSQoYRAgMBAAECggEAeDGdEkYNCGQLe8pvg8Z0ccoSGpeTxpqGrNEKhjfi6NrB
                  NwyVav10iq4FxEmPd3nobzDPkAftfvWc6hKaCT7vyTkPspCMOsQJ39/ixOk+jqFx
                  lNa1YxyoZ9IV2DIHR1iaj2Z5gB367PZUoGTgstrbafbaNY9IOSyojCIO935ubbcx
                  DWwL24XAf51ez6sXnI8V5tXmrFlNXhbhJdH8iIxNyM45HrnlUlOk0lCK4gmLJjy9
                  10IS2H2Wh3M5zsTpihH1JvM56oAH1ahrhMXs/rVFXXkg50yD1KV+HQiEbglYKUxO
                  eMYtfaY9i2CuLwhDnWp3oxP3HfgQQhD09OEN3e0IlQKBgQDZ/3poG9TiMZSjfKqL
                  xnCABMXGVQsfFWNC8THoW6RRx5Rqi8q08yJrmhCu32YKvccsOljDQJQQJdQO1g09
                  e/adJmCnTrqxNtjPkX9txV23Lp6Ak7emjiQ5ICu7iWxrcO3zf7hmKtj7z+av8sjO
                  mDI7NkX5vnlE74nztBEjp3eC0wKBgQDV2GeJV028RW3b/QyP3Gwmax2+cKLR9PKR
                  nJnmO5bxAT0nQ3xuJEAqMIss/Rfb/macWc2N/6CWJCRT6a2vgy6xBW+bqG6RdQMB
                  xEZXFZl+sSKhXPkc5Wjb4lQ14YWyRPrTjMlwez3k4UolIJhJmwl+D7OkMRrOUERO
                  EtUvc7odCwKBgBi+nhdZKWXveM7B5N3uzXBKmmRz3MpPdC/yDtcwJ8u8msUpTv4R
                  JxQNrd0bsIqBli0YBmFLYEMg+BwjAee7vXeDFq+HCTv6XMva2RsNryCO4yD3I359
                  XfE6DJzB8ZOUgv4Dvluie3TB2Y6ZQV/p+LGt7G13yG4hvofyJYvlg3RPAoGAcjDg
                  +OH5zLN2eqah8qBN0CYa9/rFt0AJ19+7/smLTJ7QvQq4g0gwS1couplcCEnNGWiK
                  72y1n/ckvvplmPeAE19HveMvR9UoCeV5ej86fACy8V/oVpnaaLBvL2aCMjPLjPP9
                  DWeCIZp8MV86cvOrGfngf6kJG2qZTueXl4NAuwkCgYEArKkhlZVXjwBoVvtHYmN2
                  o+F6cGMlRJTLhNc391WApsgDZfTZSdeJsBsvvzS/Nc0burrufJg0wYioTlpReSy4
                  ohhtprnQQAddfjHP7rh2LGt+irFzhdXXQ1ybGaGM9D764KUNCXLuwdly0vzXU4HU
                  q5sGxGrC1RECGB5Zwx2S2ZY=
                  -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

  clusters:
  - name: service-http
    type: STRICT_DNS
    lb_policy: ROUND_ROBIN
    load_assignment:
      cluster_name: service-http
      endpoints:
      - lb_endpoints:
        - endpoint:
            address:
              socket_address:
                address: service-http
                port_value: 80
```